# pandas reading dates from csv in yy-mm-dd format

Tags: python, date, csv, pandas, formats

I have a csv files with dates in the format displayed as dd-mmm-yy and i want to read in the format yyyy-mm-dd. parse dates option works but it not converting dates correct before 2000
Example: actual date is 01-Aug-1968. It is displayed as 01-Aug-68. Pandas date parase and correction=true reads the date as 01-Aug-2068.

Is there any option to read the date in pandas in the correct format for the dates before 2000.

Comment: I don't know how pandas pulls in dateutil, but [this issue](https://github.com/dateutil/dateutil/issues/84) might be a place to start.

Comment: What version of pandas are you using? With 0.16.2 `pd.to_datetime('01-Aug-68')` gives me `Timestamp('1968-08-01 00:00:00')`

Comment: Please post sample raw input data to avoid any ambiguities

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
import datetime
```

let's assume you have a csv like this:

```
mydates
18-Aug-68
13-Jul-45
12-Sep-00
20-Jun-10
15-Jul-60
```

Define your date format

```
d = lambda x: pd.datetime.strptime(x, '%d-%b-%y')
```

Put a constraint on them

```
dateparse = lambda x: d(x) if d(x) < datetime.datetime.now() else d(x) - relativedelta(years=100)
```

read your csv:

```
df = pd.read_csv("myfile.csv", parse_dates=['mydates'], date_parser=dateparse)
```

here is your result:

```
print df

     mydates
0 1968-08-18
1 1945-07-13
2 2000-09-12
3 2010-06-20
4 1960-07-15
```

Voilà