# Working on dates with mm-dd-YY & YY-mm-dd format in pandas

Tags: python, date, datetime

I am trying to do a simple test on pandas capabilities to handle dates & format.
For that i have created a dataframe with values like below. :

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'date1' : ['10-11-11','12-11-12','10-10-10','12-11-11',
                      '12-12-12','11-12-11','11-11-11']})
```

Here I am assuming that the values are dates. And I am converting it into proper format using pandas' to_datetime function.

```
df['format_date1'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date1'])
print(df)

Out[3]:
      date1 format_date1
0  10-11-11   2011-10-11
1  12-11-12   2012-12-11
2  10-10-10   2010-10-10
3  12-11-11   2011-12-11
4  12-12-12   2012-12-12
5  11-12-11   2011-11-12
6  11-11-11   2011-11-11
```

Here, Pandas is reading the date of the dataframe as "MM/DD/YY" and converting it in native format (i.e. YYYY/MM/DD). I want to check if Pandas can take my input indicating that the date format is actually "YY/MM/DD" and then let it convert into its native format. This will change the value of row no.: 5. To do this, I have run following code. But it is giving me an error.

```
df3['format_date2'] = pd.to_datetime(df3['date1'], format='%Y/%m/%d')

ValueError: time data '10-10-10' does not match format '%Y/%m/%d' (match)
```

I have seen the sort of solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32131742/pandas-reading-dates-from-csv-in-yy-mm-dd-format). But I was hoping to get a little easy and crisp answer.

Comment: If you want to parse the dates with `year` taking the first place, you could do: `df['format_date1'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date1'], yearfirst=True)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`%Y` in the format specifier takes the 4-digit year (i.e. 2016). `%y` takes the 2-digit year (i.e. 16, meaning 2016). Change the `%Y` to `%y` and it should work.

Also the dashes in your format specifier are not present. You need to change your format to `%y-%m-%d`

Comment: Click for an overview of the `format` (with all possible options) [here](http://strftime.org/)